# SpringMVC - Displaying objects in form:options

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4, spring-form

Hi I am completely from a mobile background, so Spring is new to me, I have currently I have a form called as 
BusinessForm here are the contents

```
public class BusinessForm 
{
 private String selectedBusinessId; //getters and setters included
 private List businessNameList; //getters and setters included - list of Business class Objects
  private List businessIdList; //getters and setters included  - lisy of Business class Objects
//Business class defined below 
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
@Controller 
public class HomeController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ExceptionHandler({CutsomException.class})
    public ModelAndView showHome()
    {
         //Init BusinessForm class, its defined above...
         //set values of businessNameList...
         //set values of businessIdList...
         BusinessForm businessForm = new BusinessForm();
         businessForm.setBusinessNameList(....);
         businessForm.setBusinessIdList(....);
         return ModelAndView("MyView","businessForm", businessForm)
    }
}
```

Here is my view (I will show only the form to avoid showing everyhting else)

**MyView.jsp**

```
<form:form action="blah" method="post" modelAttribute="businessForm">
<form:select path="selectedBusinessId">
<form:option value="">Select ID</form:option>
<form:options items="${businessForm.businessIdList}" item/>
</form:select>              
</form:form>
```

**So right now my businessIdList seen is above code for form:options items attribute is a list of "Business" objects and the Business objects have private variables businessName and businessId with getter and setters**

```
public class Business
{
  private String businessId; //with getters and setter 
  private String businessName; //with getters and setters 
}
```

so in the form above once I open the drop down its actually showing me a list, but that String is nothing but the toString() function of Business class. So my drop down items are looking like com.xxx.Business@c291000. **Wihtout overriding toString() of Business class,**  how do I make my form to display the actual businessId on the drop down of the form list. The reason is I want to get another form:select and display another list of businessName. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The title might be misleading, if anyone understood the scenario ...wpuld greatly appreciate if you can edit the title. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your

```
<form:select path="selectedBusinessId">
    <form:option value="">Select ID</form:option>
    <form:options items="${businessForm.businessIdList}" item/>
</form:select>
```

to

```
<form:select path="selectedBusinessId">
    <form:option value="">Select ID</form:option>
    <form:options items="${businessForm.businessIdList}" itemValue="businessId" itemLabel="businessName" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: +1 for understanding and getting me the right direction